# Blurred Screenshot of a view being drawn by UIBezierPath

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I'm drawing my graph view using `UIBezierPath`methods and coretext. I use  `addQuadCurveToPoint:controlPoint:` method to draw curves on graph. I also use `CATiledLayer` for the purpose of rendering graph with large data set on x axis. I draw my whole graph in an image context and in `drawrect:` method of my view I draw this image in my whole view. Following is my code.

```
- (void)drawImage{

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.frame.size, NO, 0.0);

        // Draw Curves 
        [self drawDiagonal];

        UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        [screenshot retain];
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{

    NSLog(@"Draw iN rect with Bounds: %@",NSStringFromCGRect(rect));
    [screenshot drawInRect:self.frame];
}
```

However in screenshot the curves drawn between two points are not smooth. I've also set the Render with Antialiasing to YES in my info plist. Please see screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'd have to see how you construct the `UIBezierPath`, but in my experience, for smooth curves, the key issue is whether the slope of the line between a curve's control point and the end point of that particular segment of the curve is equal to the slope between the next segment of the curve's start point and its control point. I find that easier to draw general smoooth curves using `addCurveToPoint` rather than `addQuadCurveToPoint`, so that I can adjust the starting and ending control points to satisfy this criterion more generally.

To illustrate this point, the way I usually draw `UIBezierPath` curves is to have an array of points on the curve, and the angle that the curve should take at that point, and then the "weight" of the `addCurveToPoint` control points (i.e. how far out the control points should be). Thus, I use those parameters to dictate the second control point of a `UIBezierPath` and the first controlPoint of the next segment of the `UIBezierPath`. So, for example:

```
@interface BezierPoint : NSObject
@property CGPoint point;
@property CGFloat angle;
@property CGFloat weight;
@end

@implementation BezierPoint

- (id)initWithPoint:(CGPoint)point angle:(CGFloat)angle weight:(CGFloat)weight
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        self.point  = point;
        self.angle  = angle;
        self.weight = weight;
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

And then, an example of how I use that:

```
- (void)loadBezierPointsArray
{
    // clearly, you'd do whatever is appropriate for your chart.
    // this is just a unclosed loop. But it illustrates the idea.

    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2.0, 50);

    _bezierPoints = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
            [[BezierPoint alloc] initWithPoint:CGPointMake(startPoint.x, startPoint.y) 
                                         angle:M_PI_2 * 0.05
                                        weight:100.0 / 1.7],
            [[BezierPoint alloc] initWithPoint:CGPointMake(startPoint.x + 100.0, startPoint.y + 70.0) 
                                         angle:M_PI_2
                                        weight:70.0 / 1.7],
            [[BezierPoint alloc] initWithPoint:CGPointMake(startPoint.x, startPoint.y + 140.0)
                                         angle:M_PI
                                        weight:100.0 / 1.7],
            [[BezierPoint alloc] initWithPoint:CGPointMake(startPoint.x - 100.0, startPoint.y + 70.0)
                                         angle:M_PI_2 * 3.0
                                        weight:70.0 / 1.7],
            [[BezierPoint alloc] initWithPoint:CGPointMake(startPoint.x + 10.0, startPoint.y + 10)
                                         angle:0.0
                                        weight:100.0 / 1.7],
            nil];
}

- (CGPoint)calculateForwardControlPoint:(NSUInteger)index
{
    BezierPoint *bezierPoint = _bezierPoints[index];

    return CGPointMake(bezierPoint.point.x + cosf(bezierPoint.angle) * bezierPoint.weight,  
                       bezierPoint.point.y + sinf(bezierPoint.angle) * bezierPoint.weight);
}

- (CGPoint)calculateReverseControlPoint:(NSUInteger)index
{
    BezierPoint *bezierPoint = _bezierPoints[index];

    return CGPointMake(bezierPoint.point.x - cosf(bezierPoint.angle) * bezierPoint.weight,  
                       bezierPoint.point.y - sinf(bezierPoint.angle) * bezierPoint.weight);
}

- (UIBezierPath *)bezierPath
{
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    BezierPoint *bezierPoint = _bezierPoints[0];

    [path moveToPoint:bezierPoint.point];

    for (NSInteger i = 1; i < [_bezierPoints count]; i++)
    {
        bezierPoint = _bezierPoints[i];

        [path addCurveToPoint:bezierPoint.point
                controlPoint1:[self calculateForwardControlPoint:i - 1] 
                controlPoint2:[self calculateReverseControlPoint:i]];
    }

    return path;
}
```

---

When I render this into a `UIImage` (using the code below), I don't see any softening of the image, but admittedly the images are not identical. (I'm comparing the image rendered by `capture` against that which I capture manually with a screen snapshot by pressing power and home buttons on my physical device at the same time.)

If you're seeing some softening, I would suggest `renderInContext` (as shown below). I wonder if you writing the image as JPG (which is lossy). Maybe try PNG, if you used JPG.

```
- (void)drawBezier
{
    UIBezierPath *path = [self bezierPath];

    CAShapeLayer *oval = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    oval.path = path.CGPath;
    oval.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    oval.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    oval.lineWidth = 5.0;
    oval.strokeStart = 0.0;
    oval.strokeEnd = 1.0;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:oval];
}

- (void)capture
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size, NO, 0.0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // save the image

    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenshot);
    NSString *documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
    NSString *imagePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"];
    [data writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];

    // send it to myself so I can look at the file

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagePath];
    UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[url]
                                                                         applicationActivities:nil];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: First of all a bundle of thanks for your answer. I'll definitely try this. If you want to see how I'm drawing curves then you can see this question posted by me & answered by me as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719143/draw-graph-curves-with-uibezierpath Infact you've given a perfect answer to that question. However my problem is more conserned with sharp edges of curved lines rather then smooth curves. The curve edges are smooth if I directly draw them on view. Drawing whole view with CATiledLayer was causing some problems so I've opted for drawing whole graph as an image.

Comment: @AbidHussain My code, or, more importantly, the observation of slopes of the control points and the ending/starting points, addresses what I'd call the "first derivative discontinuity", the fact that the curve makes a sharp turn at a point. If there's another problem you're trying to solve, let me know. Sounds like you're describing some rendering problem, but I'm not following your challenge entirely. I thought you were just trying to solve the discontinuity issue. In terms of rendering, I generally just create a `CAShapeLayer` and set its path to be my `UIBezierPath`.

Comment: yes, infact I'm facing blurred rendering of curves while taking a screenshot of my drawing inside UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions. The rendering is all right if I draw it directly on UIView instead of drawing a UIImage of my drawing on UIView.

Comment: @AbidHussain Have you tried `renderInContext` as in my updated answer? Also, are you saving as PNG or JPEG. Former is probably better, as it's lossless. I don't see blurring when I use the technique in my answer.