# program to plot UIBezierPaths?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, animation, uibezierpath

I'm doing a lot of animations in `iOS` using `UIBezierPaths` and have been manually tweaking the control points until I get the curve I want. Is there a program I can buy that will let me tweak the path with handles like the PS pen tool does then **map** the control points for me or is there a way to take a curve drawn in **PhotoShop**, Illustrator, or the like  and convert it somehow to a `UIBezierPath`.

Im wasting so much time tweaking these animations it seems like there has to be a better way.

```
UIBezierPath *runnerPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [runnerPath moveToPoint:P(1100, 463)];
    [runnerPath addCurveToPoint:P(872, 357)
                 controlPoint1:P(967, 453)
                 controlPoint2:P(1022, 366)];
    [runnerPath addCurveToPoint:P(503, 366)
                 controlPoint1:P(664, 372)
                 controlPoint2:P(699, 480)];
```

---

---

**Answered** by Kjuly: PaintCode, Perfect!

[image: Answered by Kjuly: PaintCode, Perfect!]

Comment: See the answers on following questions

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719143/draw-graph-curves-with-uibezierpath

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021883/blurred-screenshot-of-a-view-being-drawn-by-uibezierpath

Comment: Well, those are both questions about paths but they dont realy address my question. I know how to make, calculate, and implement bezier paths. I was just looking for an easier / faster way to plot the points themselves

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [PaintCode](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/paintcode/id507897570?mt=12):

> Designing an attractive, resolution-independent user interface is hard, especially if you have to program your drawing code. PaintCode is a simple vector drawing app that instantly generates resolution-independent Objective-C and C#/MonoTouch drawing code.

Not tried, but I think it'll work as you want.

However, as you see, the price ($99) is so high. :$

So what I'll do in this case is drawing multiple lines together with different colors, select the best one to do the next drawing. Of course, it is better to do it with Photoshop or GIMP. Tedious work..

Comment: Kjuly, you nailed it! PaintCode has a demo version which I downloaded and tried. Its exactly what I need and does much, much more. Downloading the full version now. Thanks!!!