# How to draw line chart with smooth curve in iOS?

Tags: ios, charts, curve

I have some points like
(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3)...

Now I want to draw a chart with smooth curve?

I'm trying to draw as below

```
-(void)drawPrices
{
    NSInteger count = self.prices.count;
    
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath]; 
    path.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;

    for(int i=0; i<count-1; i++)
    {
        CGPoint controlPoint[2];
        
        CGPoint p = [self pointWithIndex:i inData:self.prices];
        if(i==0)
        {
            [path moveToPoint:p];
        }

        CGPoint nextPoint, previousPoint, m;
        nextPoint = [self pointWithIndex:i+1 inData:self.prices];
        previousPoint = [self pointWithIndex:i-1 inData:self.prices];
        
        if(i > 0) {
            m.x = (nextPoint.x - previousPoint.x) / 2;
            m.y = (nextPoint.y - previousPoint.y) / 2;
        } else {
            m.x = (nextPoint.x - p.x) / 2;
            m.y = (nextPoint.y - p.y) / 2;
        }
        
        controlPoint[0].x = p.x + m.x * 0.2;
        controlPoint[0].y = p.y + m.y * 0.2;
        
        // Second control point
        nextPoint = [self pointWithIndex:i+2 inData:self.prices];
        previousPoint = [self pointWithIndex:i inData:self.prices];
        p = [self pointWithIndex:i + 1 inData:self.prices];
        m = zeroPoint;
        
        if(i < self.prices.count - 2) {
            m.x = (nextPoint.x - previousPoint.x) / 2;
            m.y = (nextPoint.y - previousPoint.y) / 2;
        } else {
            m.x = (p.x - previousPoint.x) / 2;
            m.y = (p.y - previousPoint.y) / 2;
        }
        
        controlPoint[1].x = p.x - m.x * 0.2;
        controlPoint[1].y = p.y - m.y * 0.2;
        
        [path addCurveToPoint:p controlPoint1:controlPoint[0] controlPoint2:controlPoint[1]];
    }
    
    CAShapeLayer *lineLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    lineLayer.path = path.CGPath;
    lineLayer.lineWidth = LINE_WIDTH;
    lineLayer.strokeColor = _priceColor.CGColor;
    lineLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;

    [self.layer addSublayer:lineLayer];
}
```

but in some situation, the line will "go back" like
[image]

Is there any better way to do that?

Comment: Here is a really good example for Square, https://github.com/jharwig/PPSSignatureView

Answer (score 12):

I've got you another solution which I used to success.
It requires SpriteKit, which has a fantastic tool called `SKKeyFrameSequence` which is capable of spline interpolation as shown in [this tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skkeyframesequence/using_keyframe_sequence_to_effect_custom_interpolation) provided by Apple.

So the idea is that you'll create the correct SKKeyFrameSequence object like this (assuming your data is in an array of `(CGFloat, CGFloat)` (x, y) tuples):

```
let xValues = data.map { $0.0 }
let yValues = data.map { $0.1 }
let sequence = SKKeyFrameSequence(keyFrameValues: yValues,
                                  times: xValues.map { NSNumber($0) })
sequence.interpolationMode = .spline

let xMin = xValues.min()!
let xMax = xValues.max()!
```

Then, if you divide the interpolated spline into 200 pieces (change this value if you want, but for me this resulted in smooth waves to human eyes), you can draw a path consisting of small lines.

```
var splinedValues = [(CGFloat, CGFloat)]()
stride(from: xMin, to: xMax, by: (xMax - xMin) / 200).forEach {
    splinedValues.append((CGFloat($0),
                          sequence.sample(atTime: CGFloat($0)) as! CGFloat))
}
```

Then finally the path (I will use SwiftUI, but you can use UIKit the same way too.):

```
Path { path in
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: splinedValues[0].0, y: splinedValues[0].1))

    for splineValue in splinedValues.dropFirst() {
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: splineValue.0, y: splineValue.1))
    }
}
```

For the values

```
[(1, 4), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 5), (5, 3), (6, -1), (7, -2), (8, -2.5), (9, -2), (10, 0), (11, 4)]
```

I've gotten a graph like this with the method described above: (I added the points too to evaluate the result better)

[image]

Comment: What is your `data` object defined as in the example?

Comment: its `var data: [(CGFloat, CGFloat)]`

Comment: Do you have any more complete code for how to achieved this?

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer at [Draw Graph curves with UIBezierPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719143/draw-graph-curves-with-uibezierpath)

And try implement with the code

```
+ (UIBezierPath *)quadCurvedPathWithPoints:(NSArray *)points
{
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    NSValue *value = points[0];
    CGPoint p1 = [value CGPointValue];
    [path moveToPoint:p1];

    if (points.count == 2) {
        value = points[1];
        CGPoint p2 = [value CGPointValue];
        [path addLineToPoint:p2];
        return path;
    }

    for (NSUInteger i = 1; i < points.count; i++) {
        value = points[i];
        CGPoint p2 = [value CGPointValue];

        CGPoint midPoint = midPointForPoints(p1, p2);
        [path addQuadCurveToPoint:midPoint controlPoint:controlPointForPoints(midPoint, p1)];
        [path addQuadCurveToPoint:p2 controlPoint:controlPointForPoints(midPoint, p2)];

        p1 = p2;
    }
    return path;
}

static CGPoint midPointForPoints(CGPoint p1, CGPoint p2) {
    return CGPointMake((p1.x + p2.x) / 2, (p1.y + p2.y) / 2);
}

static CGPoint controlPointForPoints(CGPoint p1, CGPoint p2) {
    CGPoint controlPoint = midPointForPoints(p1, p2);
    CGFloat diffY = abs(p2.y - controlPoint.y);

    if (p1.y < p2.y)
        controlPoint.y += diffY;
    else if (p1.y > p2.y)
        controlPoint.y -= diffY;

    return controlPoint;
}
```

Thanks user1244109 ^_^.