# How to find Intersection of curve and line?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgcontext

I am drawing the curve and line by giving 11 points.Is it possible to detect the point of intersection of two lines (or) two curves (or) one line and one curve.

I am **drawing line** using

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

for (int i = 0; i < [_points count]; i++)
{
    CGPoint pt = [[_points objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];
    if (i == 0)
    {
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, pt.x+1, pt.y+1);
    }
    else
    {
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, pt.x+1, pt.y+1);
    }
}

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0f);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, curveColor.CGColor);
CGContextAddPath(context, path);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
CGPathRelease(path);
```

**Curve Draw**

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

for (int i = 0; i < [_points count]; i++)
{
    CGPoint pt = [[_points objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];

    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGPoint(pt));

    if (i == 0)
    {
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, pt.x, pt.y);
    }
    else
    {
        CGPoint curP = [[_points objectAtIndex:i-1] CGPointValue];
        float delta = 1.0f;
        for (float pointX = curP.x; fabs(pointX - pt.x) > 1e-5f; pointX += delta)
        {
            float pointY = func(i-1, pointX);
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, pointX, pointY);
        }
    }
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0f);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, curveColor.CGColor);
CGContextAddPath(context, path);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
CGPathRelease(path);
```

By using these codes how to find the intersection points.

Comment: I think you know the math you will have to do it in objective c yourself not big deal make a function for it

Answer (score 3):

- To find the intersection point of two lines, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690103/intersection-between-two-lines-in-coordinates/15692290#15692290).
- To intersect a line and a curve - well your curve is just a set of lines, so the line intersects the set of lines if the line intersects any one of the lines in the set.
- To intersect a curve and a curve - check each line in one curve against each line in the other.

And there are various ways to optimize like colliding the bounding rectangles of the curves or lines first.

Comment: your first point link giving the true/false condition. for that i had many ways. But the thing is that i want the intersection point.

Comment: for 2nd and 3rd i dont know how to do that. thats y i posted the question here. Thanks

Comment: @Hack_123: Ok, well I did a bit more googling and found an objective-c answer to give you the intersection point. Link updated. For 2 and 3, you use a for loop. Literally, say you have line X with curve of lines A, B, C, D, and E. You apply the algorithm from #1 between X and A. If it's a hit, that's your answer. If not, you apply it to X and B. If it's a hit, that's your answer. If not, try C, etc. If none match then there's no intersection.

Comment: Thanks for your replay... For Line-Line intersection its working... For Curve-Curve and Line-Curve i will check and let u know..