# How to create a random closed smooth CGPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibezierpath, cgpath

I am trying to find a way to create a random closed smooth path (`CGPath` or `UIBezierPath`). I have read about the [De Casteljau's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Casteljau%27s_algorithm) and tons other articles about Bezier paths but it does not seem to fit to what I try to achieve.

I thought about creating a circle CGPath. Then I would multiplicate the path by a function that would distort the positions of the points say, sine or cosine. However I don't know if this is the right direction to go since the path would not have a random shape.

```
CGMutablePathRef circle = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddArc(circle, nil, 0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 2 * M_PI, 0.0f, true);
...
CGPathRelease(circle);
```

It would be great if anyone could point me in a right direction how to start implementing it. Example of a path I am trying to generate:

[image]

Comment: Even a non-selfintersecting closed smooth path can be quite "complicated". Can you specify some restrictions on the desired path?

Comment: Off the top of my head, it might be helpful to generate the waypoints in polar, rather than cartesian coordinates. Randomly vary the radius as you walk around the circle; then your problem is "just" interpolation. For that, look into the [Catmull-Rom spline](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8731493/) procedure, which will generate a path _through_ points, rather than around them.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, great minds think alike. Your explanation, using polar coordindates, is a little easier to follow than mine. Take a look at the sample project linked from my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you've drawn looks like a distorted circle.

Assuming that's what you are after, here is what I would do:

Write code that steps an angle from 0 to 2pi by a fixed number of steps. (Try 8) Have the angle vary by some small random amount less than ± pi/steps.

Pick a base radius that is somewhat less than 1/2 the length of a side of the enclosing square, so there is room to make your points go inside or outside the base radius without going outside your bounding square. Try 3/8 of your bounding box length.

For each slightly randomized angle value along the circle, calculate a radius value that is base radius ± a random value from 0 to base radius/2.

Use sine and cosine to convert your angle and radius values into x and y coordinates for a point.

Add each point to an array. If you use those points to create a closed path, it would give you an 8-sided irregular non-selfintersecting polygon that is a distorted circle.

Now use those points as the control points for a Catmull-Rom spline to turn it into a smooth curve.

EDIT: I created a project on github called [RandomBlobs](https://github.com/DuncanMC/RandomBlobs) that does what I describe above, as well as another approach:

Break the square area into a 3x3 grid of smaller squares. Ignore the center square.
Walk around the 8 remaining squares clockwise. For each square, pick a random x/y coorindate inside the square (but prevent it from getting too close to the edges.)
Create closed UIBezierPath connecting the 8 points in order.
Use Catmull-Rom smoothing to turn the irregular octagon into a smooth curve.

Yet a third approach would probably be even simpler:

Use a circular layout like in the first approach outlined above. Pick random control points. But then instead of using Catmull-Rom splines, bisect the angle between each pair of endpoints on the distorted circle and add a control point for a quadratic Bezier curve, also with a randomized radius value. So as you walk around the circle, you'd have alternating endpoints and control points. You might need to add some constraints to the bezier control points so you don't have "kinks" in your curved shape (In order to avoid kinks, the control points for neighboring Bezier curves need to follow a line through the shared end-point of the two curves.)

---

Here are a couple of sample images from the RandomBlobs project. The images I've uploaded are scaled down. The program optionally shows the control points it uses to generate each image, but you can't really see the control points in the scaled-down image.

First, a circle-based blob (using the first method that Josh Caswell and I suggested):
[image: Circle-based blob]
In that picture, the starting circle shape is shown in light gray:

And second, a blob based on the second square-based technique I described:

[image: Square-based blob]

And in that picture, the grid of squares is shown for reference. The shape is based on a random point in each of the points in the grid (excluding the center square).

Comment: Thanks Duncan. Your post is very helpful. I will implement it.

Comment: @reecon, I'm not sure why, but I decided to tackle your problem as an example project. After MUCH too much work, I created a project on github at https://github.com/DuncanMC/RandomBlobs that does what you asked for 2 different ways. The first way uses the circle-slicing method described in my answer above, and the second way breaks the view into a grid of 9 squares, skips the center square, and then picks random points in each square, moving clockwise, and forms a closed path that joins the 8 points. The 2 types of shape have a different feel to them.

Comment: Great piece of code! I wanted to tackle the problem during the weekend but it looks like you made my day. That's why I love StackOverflow so much. You can share and cooperate and have fun with code! Thank's man.

Answer (score 2):

I've try to build your path, but it's not perfect... Anyhow, I'll share my test ;-D Hop this can help.

```
//
//  DrawView.h
//  test
//
//  Created by Armand DOHM on 03/03/2014.
//
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DrawView : UIView

@end


//
//  DrawView.m
//  test
//
//  Created by Armand DOHM on 03/03/2014.
//
//

#import "DrawView.h"
#import <math.h>

@implementation DrawView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    float r; //radius
    float rmax = MIN(rect.size.height,rect.size.width) * .5; //max radius
    float rmin = rmax * .1; //min radius

    NSMutableArray *points = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    /*cut a circle into x pies. for each of this pie take a point at a random radius
     link all of this point with quadcurve*/

    for (double a=0;a < 2 * M_PI;a += M_PI / 10) {
        r = rmin +  ((arc4random_uniform((int)(rmax - rmin) * 100)) / 100.0f);
        CGPoint p = CGPointMake((rect.size.width / 2) + (r * cos (a)) , (rect.size.height / 2) + (r * sin (a)));
        [points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:p]];
    }


    UIBezierPath *myPath=[[UIBezierPath alloc]init];
    myPath.lineWidth=2;
    [myPath strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];

    r = rmin +  ((arc4random_uniform((int)(rmax - rmin) * 100)) / 100.0f);
    [myPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake((rect.size.width / 2) + (r * cos (0)) , (rect.size.height / 2) + (r * sin (0)))];


    for (int i = 0; i < points.count; i+=2) {
        NSValue *value = [points objectAtIndex:i];
        CGPoint p1 = [value CGPointValue];
        value = [points objectAtIndex:(i+1)];
        CGPoint p2 = [value CGPointValue];
        [myPath addQuadCurveToPoint:p2 controlPoint:p1];
    }


    [myPath closePath];

    [myPath stroke];
}

@end
```