# IOS: Is possible to rounder radius with different value in each corner

Tags: ios, layer, uibezierpath

I want to rounder my `UIView` with the value like that
`top-left-radius:20;` `bottom-right-radius:5;` `bottom-left-radius:5;` and `top-right-radius:10;`

```
   //For rounder `UIRectCornerBottomLeft & UIRectCornerBottomRight` I use

    UIBezierPath *maskPath0 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.messageView.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0)];

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer0 = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    maskLayer0.frame = self.bounds;
    maskLayer0.path  = maskPath0.CGPath;
    self.messageView.layer.mask = maskLayer0;


    //For rounder `TopRight` I use

    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.messageView.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
    maskLayer.path  = maskPath.CGPath;
    self.messageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;


    //For rounder `TopLeft` I use

    UIBezierPath *maskPath2 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.messageView.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(20.0, 20.0)];

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer2 = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    maskLayer2.frame = self.bounds;
    maskLayer2.path  = maskPath2.CGPath;
    self.messageView.layer.mask = maskLayer2;
```

But the result I get is the View with corner radius `TopLeft` with value 20.
How can I achieve this rounder? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to add all the corner radius using same object, as of now your last  object is applying the corner radius.

Comment: @VatsalK you are right, but now I don't know to add it in same object, can you describes it more in code. thank you so much

Comment: In that case you need to draw the shape as per your requirements, you can refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702696/drawing-smooth-curves-methods-needed) OR you can make image of the same shape and set the image as background.

Comment: On this older question, it's worth noting that the latest answer - I sent it a bounty - is perfect, just paste it in and do nothing else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`UIBezierPath` has no such method. But you can use bunch of `addLineToPoint` and `addArcWithCenter` methods to do it:

```
let minx = CGRectGetMinX(rect)
let miny = CGRectGetMinY(rect)
let maxx = CGRectGetMaxX(rect)
let maxy = CGRectGetMaxY(rect)

let path = UIBezierPath()
path.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(minx + topLeftRadius, miny))
path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(maxx - topRightRadius, miny))
path.addArcWithCenter(CGPointMake(maxx - topRightRadius, miny + topRightRadius), radius: topRightRadius, startAngle:3 * M_PI_2, endAngle: 0, clockwise: true)
path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(maxx, maxy - bottomRightRadius))
path.addArcWithCenter(CGPointMake(maxx - bottomRightRadius, maxy - bottomRightRadius), radius: bottomRightRadius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: M_PI_2, clockwise: true)
path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(minx + bottomLeftRadius, maxy))
path.addArcWithCenter(CGPointMake(minx + bottomLeftRadius, maxy - bottomLeftRadius), radius: bottomLeftRadius, startAngle: M_PI_2, endAngle: M_PI, clockwise: true)
path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(minx, miny + topLeftRadius))
path.addArcWithCenter(CGPointMake(minx + topLeftRadius, miny + topLeftRadius), radius: topLeftRadius, startAngle: M_PI, endAngle: 3 * M_PI_2, clockwise: true)
path.closePath()
```

For Obj-C:

```
CGFloat topLeftRadius = 20;
CGFloat topRightRadius = 10;
CGFloat bottomRightRadius = 5;
CGFloat bottomLeftRadius = 5;

CGFloat minx = CGRectGetMinX(self.messageView.bounds);
CGFloat miny = CGRectGetMinY(self.messageView.bounds);
CGFloat maxx = CGRectGetMaxX(self.messageView.bounds);
CGFloat maxy = CGRectGetMaxY(self.messageView.bounds);

UIBezierPath *path = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(minx + topLeftRadius, miny)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(maxx - topRightRadius, miny)];
[path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(maxx - topRightRadius, miny + topRightRadius) radius: topRightRadius startAngle: 3 * M_PI_2 endAngle: 0 clockwise: YES];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(maxx, maxy - bottomRightRadius)];
[path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(maxx - bottomRightRadius, maxy - bottomRightRadius) radius: bottomRightRadius startAngle: 0 endAngle: M_PI_2 clockwise: YES];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(minx + bottomLeftRadius, maxy)];
[path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(minx + bottomLeftRadius, maxy - bottomLeftRadius) radius: bottomLeftRadius startAngle: M_PI_2 endAngle:M_PI clockwise: YES];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(minx, miny + topLeftRadius)];
[path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(minx + topLeftRadius, miny + topLeftRadius) radius: topLeftRadius startAngle: M_PI endAngle:3 * M_PI_2 clockwise: YES];
[path closePath];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.path = path.CGPath;
self.messageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Comment: it is swift right?, i am new in iOS, i don't know swift. if you don't mind, can you add a objective-c version. thank you so much ;)

Comment: Yes, it is Swift. I've translated it into Obj-C. Hope I've not missed any ';' or '[]'

Comment: Thank you so much. but I have to go home now, I will check it in tomorrow. then I will notify you ;)

Comment: I tried your solution in objective-c but unfortunatelly, the view is gone :((

Comment: I've checked it and got successful results. What do you use as a rect? You need to use `self.messageView.bounds`. Please, check updated Obj-C code.

Comment: sorry. i'm using `self.messageView.frame` so it not working ^^

Answer (score 8):

Here's a UIBezierPath category that does what you want, following the pattern of some of the existing initializers:

```
extension UIBezierPath {
    public convenience init(roundedRect rect: CGRect, topLeftRadius: CGFloat?, topRightRadius: CGFloat?, bottomLeftRadius: CGFloat?, bottomRightRadius: CGFloat?) {
        self.init()

        assert(((bottomLeftRadius ?? 0) + (bottomRightRadius ?? 0)) <= rect.size.width)
        assert(((topLeftRadius ?? 0) + (topRightRadius ?? 0)) <= rect.size.width)
        assert(((topLeftRadius ?? 0) + (bottomLeftRadius ?? 0)) <= rect.size.height)
        assert(((topRightRadius ?? 0) + (bottomRightRadius ?? 0)) <= rect.size.height)

        // corner centers
        let tl = CGPoint(x: rect.minX + (topLeftRadius ?? 0), y: rect.minY + (topLeftRadius ?? 0))
        let tr = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - (topRightRadius ?? 0), y: rect.minY + (topRightRadius ?? 0))
        let bl = CGPoint(x: rect.minX + (bottomLeftRadius ?? 0), y: rect.maxY - (bottomLeftRadius ?? 0))
        let br = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - (bottomRightRadius ?? 0), y: rect.maxY - (bottomRightRadius ?? 0))

        //let topMidpoint = CGPoint(rect.midX, rect.minY)
        let topMidpoint = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY)

        makeClockwiseShape: do {
            self.move(to: topMidpoint)

            if let topRightRadius = topRightRadius {
                self.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - topRightRadius, y: rect.minY))
                self.addArc(withCenter: tr, radius: topRightRadius, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi/2, endAngle: 0, clockwise: true)
            }
            else {
                self.addLine(to: tr)
            }

            if let bottomRightRadius = bottomRightRadius {
                self.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY - bottomRightRadius))
                self.addArc(withCenter: br, radius: bottomRightRadius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat.pi/2, clockwise: true)
            }
            else {
                self.addLine(to: br)
            }

            if let bottomLeftRadius = bottomLeftRadius {
                self.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + bottomLeftRadius, y: rect.maxY))
                self.addArc(withCenter: bl, radius: bottomLeftRadius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi/2, endAngle: CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
            }
            else {
                self.addLine(to: bl)
            }

            if let topLeftRadius = topLeftRadius {
                self.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY + topLeftRadius))
                self.addArc(withCenter: tl, radius: topLeftRadius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi, endAngle: -CGFloat.pi/2, clockwise: true)
            }
            else {
                self.addLine(to: tl)
            }

            self.close()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sent you a bounty!   :)   BTW I fixed a trivial syntax error.

Answer (score 4):

Swift 5 UIView extension version of @Mikhail-Grebionkin's answer:

```
extension UIView {

    func makeCustomRound(topLeft: CGFloat = 0, topRight: CGFloat = 0, bottomLeft: CGFloat = 0, bottomRight: CGFloat = 0) {
        let minX = bounds.minX
        let minY = bounds.minY
        let maxX = bounds.maxX
        let maxY = bounds.maxY

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: minX + topLeft, y: minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: maxX - topRight, y: minY))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: maxX - topRight, y: minY + topRight), radius: topRight, startAngle:CGFloat(3 * Double.pi / 2), endAngle: 0, clockwise: true)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: maxX, y: maxY - bottomRight))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: maxX - bottomRight, y: maxY - bottomRight), radius: bottomRight, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2), clockwise: true)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: minX + bottomLeft, y: maxY))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: minX + bottomLeft, y: maxY - bottomLeft), radius: bottomLeft, startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2), endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi), clockwise: true)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: minX, y: minY + topLeft))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: minX + topLeft, y: minY + topLeft), radius: topLeft, startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi), endAngle: CGFloat(3 * Double.pi / 2), clockwise: true)
        path.close()

        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```